# jquery for open page in full screen without iframe

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I try to open html page in full screen using this code.
but I want to open another page in full screen without iframe.
(i.e. if i click on button than browser goes to full screen and open www.google.com in same window.)

**here is my code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>jQuery Fullscreen Plugin demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.fullscreen-min.js"></script>
    <style>
        width:90%;
        height:90%;
    </style>
    <style>
        #form
        {
            width:100%;
            height:100%
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function redirect()
        {
            $('#form').bind('click', function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var outputHolder = $("<div id='.uimodal-output'></div>");
                $("body").append(outputHolder);
                outputHolder.load($this.attr("href"), null, function() {
                    outputHolder.dialog(// whatever params you want);
                });
                return false;
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="background:white">
    <h1>jQuery Fullscreen Plugin demo</h1>
    <div id="form" style="display: none;">
        <h1>blah blah blah</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
        <button onclick="func1();">Enter Fullscreen mode (Form)
        </button>
    </div>

    <script>
        function func1(){
            $('#form').fullScreen(true)
            var url = "http://www.google.com";    
            //  $(location).attr('href',url);
            show();

            function show() {
                if(document.getElementById('form').style.display=='none') {
                    document.getElementById('form').style.display='block';
                }
            }
        } 
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {

            $(".fullscreen-supported").toggle($(document).fullScreen() != null);
            $(".fullscreen-not-supported").toggle($(document).fullScreen() == null);

            $(document).bind("fullscreenchange", function(e) {
                if ($(document).fullScreen())
                {
                    document.getElementById('form').style.display='block';
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('form').style.display='none';
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because of

```
var url = "www.google.com";
```

I think because of this your page navigate to google.com. If you want to hold it on current page than you can try below line instead of former one

```
var url = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myParentFolder/myChildFolder/myHTML.html";
```

Hope this might help you.

Comment: thanks for reply but when i use

var url = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myParentFolder/myChildFolder/myHTML.html";

$(location).attr('href',url);

its exit from fullscreen

Comment: I think if you remove gogle.com from url it will work. Have you tried it?

Comment: its done, i use full screen on page load event of other page so, when it call, its load in full screen and thanks for your answer, its also work good for page redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin for jQuery:

http://dawdeza.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/pon-tus-paginas-pantalla-completa-con.html#more